# Elastic4s. Scala module requires Jackson Databind version

Tags: scala, playframework, jackson, elastic4s

My project use Play framework ver 2.4.11, Scala ver 2.11.12

I am trying integrated [elastic4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s) into my project. this is sbt log when I add `"com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-client-esjava" % "7.0.0"` into build.sbt

```
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.11.0 
...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.5.4
```

Seem like `jackson` ver 2.11.0 belong to `elastic4s`

But when this code run

```
client.execute {
      indexInto(s"access").fields(
        "uri" -> request.uri,
        "time" -> requestTime
      )
    }
```

I got an error

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.9.8 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.9.0 and < 2.10.0
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:61) ~[jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.9.8.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:17) ~[jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.9.8.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:818) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.JacksonSupport$.<init>(JacksonSupport.scala:12) ~[elastic4s-core_2.11-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
    at com.sksamuel.elastic4s.JacksonSupport$.<clinit>(JacksonSupport.scala) ~[elastic4s-core_2.11-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
```

I add `"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.9"` into build.sbt but nothing happen

Please help me fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to exclude transitive dependencies when importing Play like:

```
libraryDependencies += 
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-client-esjava" % "7.0.0" exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-databind")
```

But maybe, elastic4s fails. Since that Play version is quite old, if the fix above does not work you will have to find a elastic4s version that supports the same version as the Play´s.

Comment: Using exclude worked for me in another context.